# How do I show that that equivalence sets form a subring to a set of equivalence sets.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is verify that $[0], [3], [6],[9]$ of the ring $Z/(12)$ form a subring of $Z/(12$). Then, how do I show that the subring is isomorphic to ring $Z/(4).$ Then show that the set of integral multiples of ay divisor of the modulus $n$ is a subring of the ring of integers modulo $n$. First, I know that$[0], [3], [6],[9]$ form a subring since any of those sets added or multiplied to another one of those sets would form a set in $Z/(12)$. However, how do I show it's isomorphic to $Z/(4)$ and how do I show that the set of integral multiples of ay divisor of the modulus $n$ is a subring of the ring of integers modulo $n$.

Comment: You must mean subring without unity, as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has no subrings with unity other than the ring itself. For it to be a subring you have to show that $a+b\in A:=\{[0],[3],[6],[9]\}$ and $ab\in A$, for any $a,b\in A$. That's equivalent to what you said. For it to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, you could for example construct a ring homomorphism and show that it is surjective and bijective (which is not too hard).

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to see that $a+b\in A:=\{[0],[3],[6],[9]\}$ holds true whenever $a,b\in A$, since $0$, $3$, $6$ and $9$ are the only numbers divisble by three in the set $\{0,1,\ldots,10,11\}$, and so any sum of these numbers will be divisible by three and thus equal to one of the elements of $A$ when you consider it modulo 12. The same argument works for the multiplication. It is a subring without unity though.

Consider the map $f:A\to\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(0):=0$, $f(3):=3$, $f(6):=2$ and $f(9):=1$. It's clearly a surjective and injective map, so all there is to check is that it's a ring homomorphism. Well it is quite clear that $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ and $f(\lambda a)$ hold for all $a,b\in A$ and all $\lambda\in\mathbb{Z}$, so this proves the isomorphism.

The general case proceeds of course quite similarly, and you should try it yourself.

Comment: Why do you say the numbers are only divisible by 0? Shouldn't the sums be able to be divisible by 12 or 0? But wouldn't a sum like $[3]+[6]= [9]$ not be able to be divisible 0?

Comment: That should have of course been three.